# How to reload UIPickerView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview, reload

hi
I am working on an iPhone app & i have to show some thing on a pickerview after receiving a response from socket, Methods of PickerView are check when application is going to be load. in my app i have to load PickerView on a button click.

After getting response in an array, When i click on button its shows a pickerview but empty. :(
SO can any body tell me how to reload the pickerview like tableView.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could use either `reloadAllComponents`  to realod all the component or `reloadComponent` to a zero-indexed number identifying a component of the picker view.

```
[myPickerView reloadAllComponents];
[myPickerView reloadComponent:IndexOfReloadComponent];
```

Read [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) documentation

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code, I hope it's work

```
[obj_Picker reloadAllComponents];
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `-reloadComponent:` or `-reloadAllComponents` (methods on [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)).

Quote:

> You can dynamically change the rows of a component by calling the reloadComponent: method, or dynamically change the rows of all components by calling the reloadAllComponents method. When you call either of these methods, the picker view asks the delegate for new component and row data, and asks the data source for new component and row counts. Reload a picker view when a selected value in one component should change the set of values in another component. For example, changing a row value from February to March in one component should change a related component representing the days of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method `- (void)reloadAllComponents` of the UIPickerView class.